# Proving there's a point between other points

Tags: calculus

> Let $g: [a, b]\to\mathbb R$ be continuous and let $x_1, \dots, x_n$ be distinct in $[a, b]$. Show that there is a point $c\in [a, b]$ such that
>   $$
> g(c)=\frac{g(x_1)+\cdots+g(x_n)}{n}.
> $$
>   (If you're stuck try the case $n=2$ first.)

I tried $n=2$ and got $$ g(c)=\frac{g(x_1)+g(x_2)}{2}$$
I think this is the average of the two points $g(x_1)$ and $g(x_2)$ so it must be true, but I don't know how to formally show it for this case, and I don't know how to extend it to a more general case.

I'm not sure if this is an application of the intermediate value theorem, if it is I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: Seems like a job for the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: Yes, prove that $\min\{g(x_i)\} \leq \frac{\sum g(x_i)}{n}\leq \max\{g(x_i)\}$ the apply the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: The intermediate value theorem says that if $f$ is continuous on a closed interval $[a,b]$, and $\min_{[a,b]} f \le y \le \max_{[a,b]}f$, then there is some $c\in [a,b]$ such that $f(c)=y$.

Now where does the average fall?

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality we can assume that $g(x_1)<g(x_2)$. From
$$
g(c)=\frac{g(x_1)+g(x_2)}{2}
$$
it follows that $g(x_1)<g(c)<g(x_2)$.

Do you see how to use the intermediate value theorem now?

Comment: I went from $g(x_1)<g(x_2)$ to $g(c)=g(x_1)+g(x_2)<g(x_2)+g(x_2)=2g(x_2)$ then $g(c)<g(x_2)$, but then how would I do this for more than 2 points? Even for the 3 point case I get like $g(x_1)+g(x_2)+g(x_3)<2g(x_2)+g(x_3)<2g(x_2)+g(x_3)$ which I can't seem to make into the required form as I could do for the n=2 case? (Hope it's clear what I'm trying to do here - trying to get ng(x) on the LHS)

Answer (score 0):

Since $g$ is continuous and $[a,b]$ compact, we know by the extreme value theorem, that $g$ attains a minimum and a maximum on $[a,b]$. Let 
$$ m:= \min_{x \in [a,b]} g(x) \quad \text{and} \quad M := \max_{x \in [a,b]} g(x) \; .$$
Since $m \leq g(x_i)$ for each $i = 1, \ldots, n$, we can deduce that 
$$\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n g(x_i) \geq \frac 1 n \cdot n \cdot m = m \; .$$
Do the same for $M$ to see that 
$$ m \leq \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n g(x_i) \leq M \; ,$$
and apply the intermediate value theorem.